# How to Group By columns created in a CASE statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I group by a column that is generated through a CASE statement in the following scenario:

```
SELECT COUNT(*),
CASE 
    WHEN heart_rate > 220-30 THEN 'above max'
    WHEN heart_rate > ROUND(0.90 * (220-30), 1) THEN 'above target'
    WHEN heart_rate > ROUND(0.50 * (220-30), 1) THEN 'within target'
    ELSE 'below target'
END AS 'hr_zone'
FROM exercise_logs
GROUP BY 'hr_zone';
```

With the above I get the following error:

`Each GROUP BY expression must contain at least one column that is not an outer reference.`

I expect to see two columns `Count` and `hr_zone`, where rows are grouped by `hr_zone`.

Comment: Just copy the case statement into the group by clause

Comment: I am voting to close because the root cause is using single quotes to refer to columns and that is a typographical error.

Comment: No it is not. The solution is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SQL Server you must group by each field you are selecting. You need to duplicate the CASE statement in the group by.

```
SELECT COUNT(*),
CASE 
    WHEN heart_rate > 220-30 THEN 'above max'
    WHEN heart_rate > ROUND(0.90 * (220-30), 1) THEN 'above target'
    WHEN heart_rate > ROUND(0.50 * (220-30), 1) THEN 'within target'
    ELSE 'below target'
END AS 'hr_zone'
FROM exercise_logs
GROUP BY 
  CASE 
    WHEN heart_rate > 220-30 THEN 'above max'
    WHEN heart_rate > ROUND(0.90 * (220-30), 1) THEN 'above target'
    WHEN heart_rate > ROUND(0.50 * (220-30), 1) THEN 'within target'
    ELSE 'below target'
  END
```

Or alternatively remove the group by and do a subselect but this may not be performent:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), hr_zone
  FROM (
       SELECT
       CASE 
           WHEN heart_rate > 220-30 THEN 'above max'
           WHEN heart_rate > ROUND(0.90 * (220-30), 1) THEN 'above target'
           WHEN heart_rate > ROUND(0.50 * (220-30), 1) THEN 'within target'
           ELSE 'below target'
       END AS 'hr_zone'
       FROM exercise_logs
    ) as hr_zones
GROUP BY hr_zone
```

Or even use UNION queries with each WHERE

```
SELECT COUNT(*), 'above max'
FROM exercise_logs
WHERE heart_rate > 220-30

UNION

SELECT COUNT(*), 'above target'
FROM exercise_logs
WHERE heart_rate > ROUND(0.90 * (220-30), 1)

--  etc.
```